# Installing Linux Mint over windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: linux-mint, windows, usb, bootable

I have found an old computer which runs Windows & Ultimate.

I have always wanted to install Linux to have a play about and decided to install on this old computer making it my current project.

I formated the USB to NFTS then made a Bootable USB using UNEBootin to boot Lixux Mint - Cinnamon 18.3.

All seemed to go well. The formating worked. I then removed the USB from this computer, and plugged it into my old computer, restarted the system, entered the BIOS and chose to priorities the USB over the HDD.

I am getting a message now and it will not let me use the bootable USB

> reboot and select proper boot device
>
> or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key.

I have downloaded the 32-bit Linux Mint Cinnamon as the computer appears to be running a 32-bit processor.

Is there any way around this error message?

Comment: Make sure that USB gets initialized during startup, otherwise the system won't know what to do with the USB drive. If that doesn't help, then re-read the instructions on Mint's website for making bootable USB drives, to make sure you didn't miss anything.

Comment: @Mioriin thank you for your answer. Can I ask how I would be able to tell if the USB was initializing at start up? would it make a difference what USB port i used? I did read that the version of Unebootin I used might be too new for a windows 7 system and might be best using a different program but wouldnt know what to use

Comment: A popular windows tool to write images to USB is Rufus ( https://rufus.akeo.ie/ ). Another option is Fedora's disk writer tool ( https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/ ). To make sure USB is initialized on POST, check the `integrated peripherals`and `boot` sections of the BIOS setup screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in a comment above, you will want to make sure you follow the Installation Guide for Mint to the letter. With that said, two items stand out in your attempts to install.

First, when you format the USB drive, I believe it is recommended that the drive be formatted to FAT32, not NTFS. I'm not sure if this would cause an issue or not.

Second, not all USB writing tools are the same and I've had issues using UNetBootin in the past. The Mint Installation Guide recommends using Etcher to create the drive.

You can find the detailed guide [HERE.](https://linuxmint.com/documentation.php)

Once you follow the official guide, please update and let us know your progress.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: thank you, I will have a look. If im honest, I followed a youtube video and it was them that recommended UnetBootin, ill give this a try